# upstream image response failed for https://res.cloudinary.com/<-----.jpg> 404

Tags: next.js, strapi, cloudinary

I'm working on a NextJS and Strapi Project. I'm using Cloudinary as my media library. But when I'm trying to render the image from cloudinary, the image isn't showing and giving this error:

```
upstream image response failed for https://res.cloudinary.com/djpxkfscg/image/upload/v1682152278/thumbnail_61_Mt_Y773_Mt_L_SL_1200_a5da8bdb0f.jpg 404
```

I don't have any idea about why this is happening. This is the Code:

```
<Image alt="ecommerce" className="h-full flex justify-center mx-auto" width={500} height={500} src={item.attributes.image.data.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url} />
```

And this is the URL:

https://res.cloudinary.com/djpxkfscg/image/upload/v1682152223/thumbnail_91z_Mokv_C_Nu_L_SL_1500_71907fafc4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Danny, one of the Developer Support Engineers over at Cloudinary.

This error is returned when the asset isn't available in your cloud.
I've had a look at our backend logs and I can see that there is no asset with that name on your account. It looks like there *was* an asset with the public ID `thumbnail_61_Mt_Y773_Mt_L_SL_1200_a5da8bdb0f`, however it was deleted via the Media Library UI about 30 minutes before this question was posted.

It should just be a case of uploading an asset and saving it to the same public ID. If that doesn't work, please reach out to us at https://support.cloudinary.com, and we'll be able to help.